# Remove element from list based on user input yes or no

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a dictionary

```
services = {
    "Waste Removal": 12.98,
    "Coffee Subscription": 32.99,
    "Lawn Mowing": 16.98,
    "Magazine Subscription": 21.98,
    "Cable TV": 23.98,
    "Music Subscription": 18.98,
}
```

I converted the dictionary into a list using `services_list = list(Catalogue.services.keys())`

I am then trying to remove elements from the list based on user input (Y/N). But the program is removing every element from the list and prints out the list line by line.
[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMBzy.png)

```
 # Convert dictionary to a list.
services_list = list(Catalogue.services.keys())
# prompt for input
for i in services_list:
    opt = input("Opt out of " + i + " (Y/N) : ")
    if opt == "Y" or "y":
        services_list.remove(i)
        print(services_list)
```

This is what I am trying to achieve:
[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ogrhd.png)

Comment: BTW, welcome back to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] if you haven't already and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) for tips. In the future, [please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself and use [code formatting](/editing-help#code) on it.

Comment: See also: [How do I do a case-insensitive string comparison?](/q/319426/4518341)

Answer (score 2):

Change up your if statement. Instead of doing `if opt == "Y" or "y":`, do `if opt == "Y" or opt == "y":`.

Comment: That's part of it, sure, but the linked issues in the question's comments are just as important.